# using string.Format and UnitTest dates

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Dates and formatting have always been a bit of a nightmare for me.
Lately I am doing lots of writing to file where dates must be convertted to strings in various formats(depending on client).

I would like to create a unittest that can consolidate the lot just put a couple of example.

The below test fails as "March 09" and "09 March" do not match.How do I make this test culture aware.
Better test anyone?

```
        [TestCase("March 09", "{0:m}")]                        
        [TestCase("March, 2008", "{0:y}")]  
             [TestCase("3/9/2008 4:05 PM", "{0:g}")                       
        public void When_stringFormat_a_date_should_match(string expected,string format)
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 03, 09, 16, 05, 07);

            string actual = String.Format(format, dt);

           assert ??                
        }
```

Comment: Why are you calling .ToString on a string?

Comment: you are right mistake.Copy and paste

Comment: Are different cultures involved as well?

Comment: @GertArnold Depending on client.Ideally should be culture agnostic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `String.ToString()`! It doesn't make sense to specify the `CultureInfo` (or even use this functio), since this always returns the original string independently of the specified culture.

IMO you have to specify the `CultureInfo` when converting the date, i.e.

```
string actual = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, dt);
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Comment: NUnit.Framework.AssertionException was unhandled by user code
  Message=  String lengths are both 16. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "3/9/2008 4:05 PM"
  But was:  "03/09/2008 16:05" when testing "3/9/2008 4:05 PM", "{0:g}"
 How could i fix the test as the dates are the same.Not sure if I should just amend the testCase or...

Comment: I must confess that I'm not entirely sure about what exactly you want to test. Currently you're only testing `String.Format`, which I'm confident the folks at Microsoft already did to a certain extent ;) And yes, since the format string `"{0:g}"` apparently returns the date with leading zeros (I didn't check this), you would have to change the test case parameters accordingly.

Comment: Btw, since you've changed the source code in the question my answer doesn't make sense anymore :) ...

Answer (score 1):

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```